# How to Custom Format Custom Data WPF 4.5?

Tags: c#, wpf, formatting, string-formatting

I am developing some software that generates reports from event data collected from some devices. The data is stored in a database. I want the user to be able to template the output filename of the report generated by the software. So when the user decides to generate a report, the output filename template they have configured is applied to the data retrieved from the database.

For example, lets say that each report has the following data template elements associated with it:

```
<Name>
<Timestamp>
<Location>
<EventType>
```

So the user could select any of these template items in any order to determine the format of the output filename. If they chose something like this:

```
<Name> <EventType> <Location> <Timestamp>.pdf
```

And lets say this is the data for the current report in the database:

```
Name = "MyReport"
EventType = "Error"
Location = "Park Ave"
Timestamp = 1-30-2013 11.00.00 AM
```

The report filename would look like this when the actual report is generated:

```
"MyReport Error Park Ave 1-30-2013 11.00.00 AM.pdf"
```

I'm struggling to come up with an elegant way of providing custom format elements like `<Name>, <Location>` etc... and building a string from data in a database or possibly an entity object. I have looked at ICustomFormatter and IFormatProvider, but I'm not sure if these are completely appropriate for what I'm doing.

I am using WPF 4.5 and my data will be driven by the Entity Framework.
Any ideas would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I saw this in my questions and that no one ever answered. Just for posterity I wanted to record what I did. I ended up using [Regex.Replace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace(v=vs.110).aspx). I used an enumeration to list the different format fields like this:

```
String pattern = String.Format("<{0}>", Template.Timestamp);
String result = Regex.Replace(pattern, data.Timestamp.ToString());
```

Where "Template" is an enumeration and "Timestamp" is the element I wanted to replace. It seemed to work for my needs.